# Why Vector iterator has type unknown in rust [Goland Rust-plugin]?

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn rust, and I am following one tutorial on YouTube. In that video, he did this:

```rust
let v1 = vec![1,2,3];
let iter = v1.iter();
let sum = iter.fold(..othercode...)
```

I was inspecting this code to figure out what's going on and found out variable `iter` has a type of unknown.

Can anyone explain to me why `v1.iter()` has type `unknown`?

Comment: *How* were you inspecting the code to conclude that `iter` has type unknown? If you have code that otherwise compiles, you can find out the type of a variable by adding a `let () = variable_name;` after the definition. That won't compile, but the exact type of the variable will be included in the error message.

Comment: I am inspecting the type of variable in my IDE GO-land with rust plugin

Comment: Then it's probably a problem of the plugin. Does it compile from the terminal, using `cargo`? If yes, file an issue to the plugin developers. If not, please post here _reproducible_ code including the _full_ error message.

Comment: yes. it does compile when i do `cargo run`. As you said i think its the problem with goland rust plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which IDE are you using and which Rust plugin is it using? Perhaps the plugin was unable to identify the type?

Assuming that `v1` has type `Vec<i32>`

then `std::slice::Iter<i32>` is the type of `iter` though these annotations are unnecessary.

```
let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
let iter: std::slice::Iter<i32> = v1.iter();
```

Comment: I am using Rust plugin in Goland IDE. Just now I tested with vscode and its giving me type of `std::slice::Iter<i32>`. I think the problem is with the rust plugin in goland. But even if vscode found the type of .iter() it didn't display the method autocomplete.  why is that?

Comment: @BipinMaharjan Try tiggering the completion manually using Ctrl+Space. VSCode has autocomplete threshold (16ms if I remember correctly) to show completions autuomatically; longer than that it requires manual triggering. See also [this issue in the rust-analyzer repo](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/7542).